# Linux AWS still looking for uninstalled version of Node and of NPM

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-ec2

I'm fairly new to Linux systems, so sorry if the question is too basic. I am using Amazon Linux 2 AMI.

I had installed version 16.4.2 of NodeJS at the beginning and was giving me compatibilities issues. Hence I tried to uninstall it and then install version 14.15.5 (which was stable on my local dev).

To uninstall the new version, I ran the command `sudo yum remove nodejs` and it apparently uninstalled NodeJS. Then I installed the old version via first `curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo bash -` and then `sudo yum install -y nodejs` (it said it was successful). But finally I ran the command `node -v` to only get:

`-bash: /home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v16.4.2/bin/node: No such file or directory`

So he's still looking for the version I uninstalled. How can I completely remove the new version and finally get the new version installed, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For anybody arriving at this post: after uninstallation, everything I had to do was stopping and rebooting the instance. Then the old version was recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Try exiting and reconnecting to the EC2 instance, it helps everytime. Also, if you haven't already upgraded the nodejs version you can upgrade using [this link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/update-node-js-version) once done, exit the instance and reconnect, works everytime.

Comment: Also, you can use nvm which is in option 3, easy to upgrade/downgrade/switch between node versions